# Pulling Map object from Firestore, getting random garbage

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Go to try and pull some documents from Firestore, but have run into a pretty big wall: no matter how hard I try, I can't pull data from the query itself. When I print the `doc.Data()` or whatever it is, it works fine:

```
map[Ext: ID:107677035991703552 Kind:link Start:0.0 Stop:8.0 URL:ONHPHmNV0m4]
```

I do:

```golang
iter := client.Collection("intro-requests").Documents(ctx)
for {
    doc, err := iter.Next()
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    var temp Request
    doc.DataTo(&temp)
    fmt.Println(temp)
    requests = append(requests, temp)
    for _, request := range requests {
        fmt.Println(doc.Data())
        createVote(s, request)
    }
    fmt.Println(doc.Data())
}
```

as per the Google example, but printing `temp` which, I get this:

```js
{ link 0 0  }
```

but also sometimes this:

```js
{  0 0  }
```

and sometimes this:

```js
{ link 0 0 ONHPHmNV0m4 }
```

What gives? I can't even fathom what's going on here. I also can't find any other valid examples, because  all of Google's examples don't go any further just printing the map, which works 100% of the time. It almost feels like the map is being turned into a byte array or something, and the program is just trying to salvage some numbers out of it.

Here's my class:

```golang
type Request struct {
    ID    string  `json:"ID"`
    Kind  string  `json:"Kind"`
    Start float64 `json:"Start"`
    Stop  float64 `json:"Stop"`
    URL   string  `json:"URL"`
    Ext   string  `json:"Ext"`
}
```

I've tried using third party deserialization packages, but nothing changes... Any clues?

Comment: Updated to show more code. And sorry, I meant "interface", not instance. Hadn't had my coffee yet... Both updated in the question. the `map[string]interface` is what `doc.DataTo()` gives that. I think I worded it poorly. From Google: "DataTo uses the document's fields to populate p, which can be a pointer to a map[string]interface{} or a pointer to a struct.". In this case, I'm trying to move it to a struct

Comment: No error; it runs fine. But when I print out `temp`, I get one of the weird random answers listed above.

Comment: Oh haha, I get you. I'm a little new to Go, old habits. Here's what it says:
`main.Request.Stop: firestore: cannot set type float64 to string`

Comment: I found this from Google:

- Null converts to nil.

- Bool converts to bool.

- String converts to string.

- Integer converts int64. When setting a struct field, any signed or unsigned.

 Sounds like it doesn't support floats maybe?

Comment: It looks like the application is attempting to set a float64 into a string. Add this code to find the type mismatch: `for k, v := range doc.Data() { fmt.Printf("%s: %T\n", k, v) }`.  Compare the output to the types in the struct fields.

Comment: Yup. That's pretty nifty! It's converting to strings. I'll try fixing when I get a sec, and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Go can't deserialize `Float64`, only `Nil`, `Bool`, `Int64`, and `String`. Weird that something like a type error would cause such behavior.

I switched my `float64`s out for `string`s, then just used `strconv.ParseFloat()`. Problem solved

Comment: The class in Go definitely was float64, but you don't get that level of control in Firebase (I had it set to "number"). Going with what you said, I'm guessing *that's* where the type mismatch was.